# Remove image from MediaRouteControllerDialog

Tags: android, chromecast

I want to remove the imageView from the MediaRouteControllerDialog since I don't have any image to display.

Comment: Why would you want to remove the ImageView? If you don't specify any image, it should hide that. Are you seeing a different behavior?

Comment: It displays a generic image, like a dark grey background.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify an image for the media (or a default one), the dialog will not show any image; there is no default image in the library to use when you don't specify one. Are you using any particular framework? The right approach to populate the metadata (including image) for a `MediaRouteControllerDialog` is to use the `MediaSessionCompat`. If you are using that approach, make sure your `MediaSessionCompat` doesn't have any pointer to any image.